# i'm confused about django statice files during deployment

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles

I'm about two months in with django. I've been following tutorials on youtube and such and one of the tutorials says that I have to use two servers when deploying my site. Django will be served from heroku and static files from amazon s3. I have to pay for two seperate servers to deploy a django app? I did not expect this and this would not be within my budget if this is so. Is he wrong or is this just for special cases like his? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sounds like the video is a bit confusing. There is a distinction between static assets, ie the CSS/JS etc that makes up your site, and dynamic media, ie any user-uploaded content.

Heroku can quite happily serve static assets from the filesystem, and their docs on deploying Django state [exactly how to do this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets). However you cannot store dynamically uploaded content on Heroku, since the filesystem is ephemeral. If your app allows this, you need to save them somewhere permanent such as S3.

Note however that S3 is *really* cheap; hosting media files there should only cost you pennies.

Comment: thanks My site will be comprised of links to youtube videos, not actual videos, and I may have images if that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 different servers for deploying your django project. You can just use a single Amazon EC2 instance then install Nginx/Apache+Supervisor+Gunicorn+Python. After that, you just need to configure the location of your static files from your virtualhost. [Here's a tutorial from digital ocean.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04)